# Let $G$ be a group. Prove that the following affirmations are equivalent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having problems doing this exercise:

> Let $G$ be a group. Prove that are equivalent:
>
> $(i)$ G is an abelian group.
>
> $(ii)$ $\phi(x)=x^{-1}$, $\forall\ x\in G$, is a morphism.
>
> $(iii)$ $\phi(x)=x^{2}$, $\forall\ x\in G$, is a morphism.

I already proved $(i)\implies (ii)$, but I can't prove $(ii) \implies (iii)$. Could someone give me any hint? Thank you!

Comment: It might be easier to do (i)$\iff$ (ii) and (i)$\iff$(iii).

Comment: It's probably easiest to prove (i) iff (ii) and (i) iff (iii).

Comment: @DerekHolt great minds think alike :)

Comment: @MikeEarnest Implies that $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$, but I don't know how to use this to prove $(iii)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I didn't thought my exercise that way. I would do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also prove $(ii) \implies (iii)$ directly, but it's a bit silly.  Suppose $\phi(x) = x^{-1}$ is a morphism. Define $\psi: G\to G, \psi(x) = x^2$; we want to show that $\psi$ is a morphism, namely that $\psi(ab) = \psi(a)\psi(b)$.

We have \begin{align*}
\psi(ab) &= abab \\
&= \phi(a^{-1})\phi(b^{-1})\phi(a^{-1})\phi(b^{-1}) \\
&= \phi(a^{-1})\phi(b^{-1}a^{-1})\phi(b^{-1})\\
&= \phi(a^{-1})ab\phi(b^{-1}) \\
&= \phi(a^{-1})\phi(a^{-1})\phi(b^{-1})\phi(b^{-1})\\
&= a^2 b^2 \\
&= \psi(a)\psi(b)
\end{align*}
Again, this is perhaps a bit ridiculous, but it does show $(ii) \implies (iii)$ without doubling back to $G$ abelian.